# Several animations with delay on of them not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do several animations on the same element, however, on one of them I need it to have a delay but its not working. Below is the code.

```js
$('#hey').animate({
  'margin-top': '100px',
}, {queue: false, duration: 1500, complete: function(){
  // alert('hey');
}});

$('#hey').animate({
  'margin-left': '100px',
}, {queue: false, duration: 1000});

$('#hey').delay(5000).animate({ // <-- this delay
  'height': '190px',
}, {queue: false, duration: 2000});
```

```css
#hey {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="hey"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [jquery delay](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) docs, the delay function works on the animation queue. It looks like you need to set `queue: true` in order for delay to do anything:

```js
$('#hey').animate({
  'margin-top': '100px',
}, {queue: false, duration: 1500, complete: function(){
  // alert('hey');
}});

$('#hey').animate({
  'margin-left': '100px',
}, {queue: false, duration: 1000});

$('#hey').delay(5000).animate({
  'height': '190px',
}, {queue: true, duration: 2000});
```

```css
#hey {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="hey"></div>
```